# Bootstrap Datepicker: Highlight days between multidate range

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Is it posible to highlight the range between two dates in a single datepicker as shown in the image using [eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) datepicker?

My configuration is

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
     multidate: 2
})
```

[image]